# Regex to remove all kinds of bullet points and numbers or characters and more

Tags: python, regex

i am trying to remove all kind of bullet points with different formats, this is basically the cases that i have:

c.2  Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+
b.1  Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+
a.1  Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+

1. Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+
   1.2  Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+
   1.1.1 Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+
   5.6.2 (S.1.C.1) Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+
   5.6.2 (S.3) Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+
   5.6.2 (S.4.C.13) Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+

i want a regex to remove the bullet points no matter what form they are in and have only :  Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+

i tried to use  `^(?:\d+\.)+\d*\s*` it works fine but it only detects 1. or 1.2 or 1.1.1 thats what i wanted in the beginning so it was correct, but now my given is changed to this.

Thank you in advance, side note: i use python3

Comment: I'd start with some catch-all like `^\w(?:\.\w)*\b(?: \([SC\d.]+\))?` that still expresses the pattern you look for, and then only make the classes more specific if you need to. Your source seems like a highly reglemented text, though, so you might be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`^[a-z\d+]\.(\d+)?\.?(\d+)?(\s\(.*\)\s)?\s+`

This one is catching all types of bullet points in your example, here's the proof:
https://regex101.com/r/sj4PgN/2

Comment: it is not catching these : 5.6.2 (S.1.C.1) i want to catch all of it and remove it later on not just 5.6.2

Comment: @PatrickElZaybak I've fixed regex

Comment: its still not detecting it all if you try this : 5.6.2 (S.4.C.13) Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+    it only detects 5.6.2 i want it to detect 5.6.2 (S.4.C.13)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 ^(?:[a-z]|\d+)(?:\.\d+)*\.?\s*(?:\([^()]*\)\s*)?
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[a-z]|\d+)` either match a char a-z or match 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)*` Optionally repeat `.` and 1+ digits
- `\.?` Match an optional dot
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(?:\([^()]*\)\s*)?` Optionally match a part `(...)` followed by optiinal spaces

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sbNzlb/1)

In the replacement use an empty string.

If the part between the parenthesis is of the given specific pattern being an uppercase char A-Z followed by a dot and digit(s):

```
^(?:[a-z]|\d+)(?:\.\d+)*\.?\s*(?:\([A-Z]\.\d+(?:\.[A-Z]\.\d+)*\)\s*)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jaqnfv/1)

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"^(?:[a-z]|\d+)(?:\.\d+)*\.?\s*(?:\([^()]*\)\s*)?"

s = ("c.2  Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+\n"
            "b.1  Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+\n"
            "a.1  Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+\n"
            "1. Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+\n"
            "1.2  Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+ \n"
            "1.1.1 Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+ \n"
            "5.6.2 (S.1.C.1) Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+\n"
            "5.6.2 (S.3) Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+\n"
            "5.6.2 (S.4.C.13) Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+")

result = re.sub(pattern, "", s, 0, re.MULTILINE)
if result:
    print(result)
```

Output

```
Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+
Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+
Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+
Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+
Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+ 
Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+ 
Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+
Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+
Employed population below international poverty line, by sex and age (%) Age: 15+
```